# How to solve a twice differentiable function

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I assumed the functions to be quadratic and then solved for it.
[Image of question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ru7Mc3vTcarhFXC08dMmICYF_MVRbgGK/view?usp=drivesdk)

I got the answer as **-10**

Comment: It is good practice to write the question in LaTeX instead of posting an image.

Comment: Sorry but I dont know how to write in LaTeX as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it as follows: $f'' = g''$ implies $f'-g' = c$ for some constant $c$, and using $f'(1) = 2$, $g'(1) = 4$ implies $c = -2$. Then $f'-g' = -2$ implies $f-g = -2x+d$ for some constant $d$, and using $f(2)=3$, $g(2)=6$ implies $d = -2$.

Hence $f-g = -2x-2$ and so $f(4)-g(4) = -2\cdot 4 -2 = -10$ as required. This agrees with you answer, without assuming the functions to be quadratic.

Comment: Thank you, this method was quick and fast.